# How to open different layouts from a custom list view depending on the text on the list view?

Tags: android, custom-lists

[image]**I have a custom listview it's onItemClick method is below**

```
if (bean.getResType().equals("Music"))
{
    ListView listView;
    View view = getView();
    if (view != null) {
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list4);


        CustomListViewAdapterMindMaps adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getContext(),
                R.layout.list, mList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Main_Activity_For_Music.class);


                //start the second activity
                startActivity(intent);

            }


        });
    }else  if (bean.getResType().equals("Video")) {

            ListView listView2;
            View view2 = getView();
            if (view2 != null) {

                listView2 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list4);


                CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getContext(),
                        R.layout.list, mList);
                listView2.setAdapter(adapter);


                listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {




                           Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Main_Activity_For_Video.class);

                            startActivity(intent);

                    }


                });

            }
```

In this listview, I am showing a different kind of list items eg.Music and video.
So if user press music item it opens a new layout and if the video is selected it open video layout.But whatever I select it always open the first layout ex.music layout.

Comment: Use _Switch_ case for that using some tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
String resource;
resource =  bean.getResType();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                    int position, long id) {

                                if(resource.equals("Music"){
                                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getContext(), Main_Activity_For_Music.class);


                                //start the second activity
                                startActivity(intent1);
                               }else if(resource.equals("Video")
                                {
                                     Intent intent2 = new Intent(getActivity(), Main_Activity_For_Video.class);

                                        startActivity(intent2);
                                 }

                            }
```

or you can also use switch case

```
switch(bean.getResType()){
case "Music":
Intent intent1 = new Intent(getContext(), Main_Activity_For_Music.class);


                                    //start the second activity
                                    startActivity(intent1);
break;
case "Video":
Intent intent2 = new Intent(getContext(), Main_Activity_For_Video.class);


                                    //start the second activity
                                    startActivity(intent1);
break;

}
```

Comment: No,actually the problem is that it is not necessary that position 0 is always Music or video.And the listview contains a long list of Music and Video.@Saurabh

Comment: if (bean.getResType().equals("Video"))I have written it but not  working@Saurabh  see my code

Comment: @ShwetabhSingh..I have updated my answer and make resource sting globally

Answer (score 0):

```
 listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                    int position, long id) {

you need 

getItemAtPosition(position); 



                                   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Main_Activity_For_Video.class);

                                    startActivity(intent);

                            }
```